SSRS: page break issue for groups while using tablix inside groups
I have a report with two groups State and City; for State I am showing the summary and City has details.
For State I am showing total for each status pending, cancelled and completed orders.
For City I have three tablix each for pending, cancelled and completed . I have created three rows in City group and placed these tablix.
The requirement is to have page break in such a way that State data is in one page then next page will have City data and there is page break between each city and state. For this I am using page break at the start and end for both groups.
Dataset for for parent table and child tablix.
The page break happens for most of the City groups but for some City there is a blank space at the end. As a result same page has data for two City.
I am getting this issue while rendering pdf.
I have used rectangle instead of have three rows for each tablix. Also I have used KeepToGether property. In some cases the city group may have data for one status, in these case I used NoRowMessage to avoid extra space taken by tablix.

I have used list also. If I use list the tablix in City group are getting merged.
